# Recreating Anypic navigation flow

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, parse-platform

Okay I need help. I clearly missing something hugely obvious.

I read almost 30 posts on this exact error, but this app is still screwing with me. I am pretty much copying the navigation flow of the Anypic app (Parse.com) since its very similar to what I want to do in my app. First of all Anypic thinks they can push a tabBar controller onto a view controller which to my knowledge does not work, so in my implementation I am presenting it modally.

I am using a storyboard! and getting references to each view controller like so:

```
self.storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
CustomViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];
```

**HERE IS THE ERROR:**
Attempt to present UITabBarController on NFWelcomeViewController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Please help!

```
NFWelcomeViewController


-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // If not logged in, present login view controller
    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    }

    else {

        // Present Notified UI
        // [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] presentTabBarController];
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"tabBar" sender:self];

        // Refresh current user with server side data -- checks if user is still valid and so on
        [[PFUser currentUser] refreshInBackgroundWithTarget:self selector:@selector(refreshCurrentUserCallbackWithResult:error:)];
    }

}
```

AppDelegate (I have this commented out for now, put ideally I want to implement it like Anypic does)

```
- (void)presentLoginViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"present login");

    NFLoginViewController *loginViewController = [[NFLoginViewController alloc] init];
    [loginViewController setDelegate:self];
    loginViewController.fields = PFLogInFieldsFacebook | PFLogInFieldsUsernameAndPassword;
    loginViewController.facebookPermissions = @[ @"basic_info", @"email" ];

    [self.welcomeViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
   // [self.welcomeViewController presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)presentLoginViewController {
    [self presentLoginViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)presentTabBarController {

    NSLog(@"present tabBar");

    self.tabBarController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBar"];

    [self.welcomeViewController.navigationController pushViewController:self.tabBarController animated:NO];

    [self.navController setViewControllers:@[ self.welcomeViewController, self.tabBarController ] animated:NO];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}
```

Comment: You can't present another controller from viewDidLoad (of a UIViewController) because the controller's view hasn't been added to the window's hierarchy at that point (hence the error message). Try it from viewDidAppear, and with animation NO, if you don't want to see the NFWelcomeViewController first.

Comment: I knew it was something I wash't understanding properly. I am going to try that fix right now